# strange characters printed when concatenate strings with memcpy

Tags: c, linux

I have developped this function:

```
bool execc(char *cmd, char *r)
{

    FILE *fp;
    char t1[1024];
    char *t2;
    memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    t1 = r;

    while (fgets(t1, sizeof(t1), fp) != NULL)
    {
    r = &r[strlen(r)];
    memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));
    }
    r = t2;
    r[strlen(r)] = '\0';

    pclose(fp);

    return true;
}
int main()
{
    char r[4096];
    int i = 51;
    execc("ls -l /", r);
    printf("result of cmd: \n %s", r);
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this program I got some strange characters, like the following:

```
result of command: 
 total xxx
drwxr-xr-x   7   1001 root    4096 août  25 16:06 xxx
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    4096 juin  30 11:45 xxx
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   12288 oct.   9 15:26 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    1024 août  28 11:48 boot
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    4096 août  26 10:51 boot-files
drwxrwxr-x   2 root   root    4096 janv. 12  2015 cdrom
drwxr-xr-x   7 xxxx xxxx  4096 juil. 14 16:43 data
drwxr-xr-x  20 root   root    4640 oct.  20 15:06 dev
drwxr-xr-x 174 root   root   12288 oct.   9 17:43 etc
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root    4096 sept. 28 17:19 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      33 août  26 10:50 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-xxxx-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      33 août  26 10:49 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-xxxx-generic
drwxr-xr-x  27 root   root    4096 avril 28 16:08 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 mai    7 17:35 lib32
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 avril 28 15:33 lib64
drwx------   2 root   root   16384 janv. 12  2015 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    4096 janv. 16  2015 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 oct.  16  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   7 root   root    4096 août  24 13:18 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 299 root   root       0 oct.  19 08:54 proc
drwx------  10 root   root    4096 oct.   5 18:03 root
drwxr-xr-x  27 root   root     940 oct.  20 14:38 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   12288 août  13 09:57 sbin
h�rwxr-xr-x   2 root   root    4096 oct.  22  2014 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root   root       0 oct.  20 14:34 sys
drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody xxxx  4096 oct.  12 12:08 tftpboot
drwxrwxrwt  19 root   root   20480 oct.  20 15:30 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   root    4096 août  27 10:24 usr
drwxr-xr-x  14 root   root    4096 avril  7  2015 var
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      30 août  26 10:46 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-xxxx-generic
3B�lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root      30 août  13 10:01 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-xxxx-generic
```

How to fix this error? I don't find the problem

Comment: 'memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));' does not do what you think it does.

Comment: ..and even if it did, it's cargo-cult buffer-clearing.

Comment: The program doesn't even compile.

Comment: I don't know why I bother, but anyway...  add more temp vars to hold intermediate results, eg 'bufLen=sizeof(r);'.  turn optimization off, USE A DEBUGGER.

Comment: I have fixed the error, just I have remplaced `memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));` by `memcpy(r, t1, sizeof(t1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sizeof(r)` returns the size of a pointer the easiest way to empty `r` is to change main to have...

```
char r[4096] = ""; /* initialize to '\0' */
```

The code should probably walk the amount of data read, not the overflow of the buffer.

```
 memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));
 r = &r[strlen(t1)]; /* walk by amount added */
```

The code seems to have been messed up.

```
 t1 = r; /* << == doesn't compile */
```

The `r = t2;` creates undefined behavior, as `t2` is never assigned.

```
r = t2;
r[strlen(r)] = '\0';
```

Try in the loop.

```
 memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));
 r = &r[strlen(t1)]; /* walk by amount added */
 r[0] = '\0'; /* terminate the string */
```

In general, if you get more than 4k of data, bad stuff happens.

```
bool execc(char *cmd, char *r)
{

   FILE *fp;
   char t1[1024];

   fp = popen(cmd, "r");
   if (fp == NULL)
   {
      return false;
   }

   while (fgets(t1, sizeof(t1), fp) != NULL)
   {
      memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));
      r = &r[strlen(t1)]; /* walk by amount added */
      r[0] = '\0'; /* terminate the string */
   }
   pclose(fp);

   return true;
}
```

Comment: I have resolved the problem of data size, you can see my later reponse

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
memcpy(r, t1, strlen(t1));
```

is copying `t1` *without* the terminating `\0`. So this line:

```
r[strlen(r)] = '\0';
```

is invalid, as `strlen(r)` will not return the correct value, as `r` is not terminated properly.

It *could* work if `r` region was filled with zeros to a whole operational range. But it is not as

```
memset(r, 0, sizeof(r));
```

will not work as you probably expect. `sizeof(r)` is just a pointer size, which is couple of bytes presumably.

Answer (score 1):

to get more than 4k of data I have made this big modification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool execc(char *cmd, char **value)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[128];
    char *tmp;
    int size;

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (size = fread (buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),fp))
    {
        buffer[size] = '\0';        
        if(*value == NULL)
        {
            *value = strdup(buffer);    
        }
        else
        {   
            tmp = *value;           
            *value = (char*)calloc(strlen(tmp)+strlen(buffer), sizeof(char));   
            memcpy(*value, tmp, strlen(tmp));
            memcpy(*value+strlen(tmp), buffer, strlen(buffer));
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    pclose(fp);

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    char *r = NULL;
    execc("ls -l /", &r);
    if(r!= NULL)
    {   
        printf("result of cmd: \n %s", r);
        free(r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```